# Where is a good AOSP Makefile to put PRODUCT_PACKAGES+=mytool

Tags: android, makefile, android-source, android-build

I'm working with an internal tool for a few users building in AOSP tree.
To enable the build of this tool it must be added to `PRODUCT_PACKAGES` variable somewhere in the make-system.

```
PRODUCT_PACKAGES+=mytool
```

Upto now I have maintained this as uncommitted changes to `/build/make/target/product/base_system.mk` I could of course fork this module and maintain my patch or maintain it as a diff and patch it when a new workspace is created.

The project now needs to be shared with a handful of coworkers, so this is a good opportunity to make it less hacky and more maintainable as a forked module requires constant merges of upstream patches.

The project only maintain one git repo for manifest and one for the tool itself.

How could I add this assignment of to a Makefile without having to maintain it as a shell script or a forked version of one of the android gits?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will have to add `mytool` to the device configuration in `device/<vendor>/<device>/device.mk`.

Even if you happen to find a way to make it work from within the `mytool` repository you probably shouldn't, because it is the job of the integrator to add modules to the device. He can hardly keep track if packages are not collected at a single point and I can think of even more problems if the integration is spread over many repositories, potentially each with an own set of access rights.

A solution I use when I want to share an early version without the hassle of integration is providing it in form of [local repo manifest](https://gerrit.googlesource.com/git-repo/+/master/docs/manifest-format.md#Local-Manifests) which combines the `mytool` repository together with a patched `device/<vendor>/<device>` repository.

Comment: For the device/vendor/device I would still have the drawbacks of an forked upstream version and I would have to maintain two versions for if we for instance builds for both hikey960 and hikey platforms. The local manifest would be essential the same as my current static manifests. Possible but not the silver bullet I was looking for.

Comment: I assumed that you also use a custom device configuration. You could fork hikey on your local server and use that instead.

Comment: Have you tried building it directly without adding to product_packages?
Ex: make mytool (from android top level folder)